# What happen when I add iPhone 6+ launch image but without @3x icon image?

Tags: ios, iphone

I tried to add iPhone 6+ launch image to project but without @3x icon images in xcode 6.1 iOS 8.
Actually it seems work fine to me.

Does that mean the scaled @2x image is used on iPhone 6+ if without @3x in image asset?

and is it true app without 3x image will be rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, @2x scaled will be used (as you can see by running in simulator or on your device). But remember that adding @3x icon required to distribute your app to the App Store.

Comment: is it true app without 3x image will be rejected? I look around some say it's rumor

Comment: @dopcn as you can see [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Comment: the document list the size of 2x 3x but didn't mention 3x is required

Comment: @dopcn It does say that if you are planning to add support for iPhone 6 plus, it is required to add `@3x` icon.